# Send email to multiple recipients with bcc 'hidden' address - Django 1.6

Tags: python, django, email, django-1.6

I'm developing an app on Django 1.6

In this app, there is a section, where a User which publishes a project can receive a message from a freelancer interested into this project.

So far this is the code I have:

```
# Send email
        if user_profile.contracting:
            subject = _('Your question on project {} has been answered')
            body = _('You can read your answer here {}')
            email = question.user.email

        else:
            subject = _('Your have a new question on project {}')
            body = _('You can read your question here: {}')
            email = project.user.email

        send_mail(subject.format(project.name),
                  body.format(
                      os.environ.get('CURRENT_URL') + '/' +
                      reverse('projects_id', args=(project.id,))[1:]),
                  'no_responder@contratalos.com', [email, 'info@contratalos.com'])

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('projects_id',
                                            args=(project.id,)))

    else:
        d = {'form': ProjectMessagesForm(request.POST)}
return render_to_response('projects/questions.html', d,
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

If you look at this line:

```
no_responder@contratalos.com', [email, 'info@contratalos.com'])
```

I'm adding the previous 'email' declaration and another recipient `info@contratalos.com`, this second recipient fails, I don't receive any error message, but the message is not sent.

I don't know what the cause could be... Since I don't have any traceback to it...

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

This line works:

```
no_responder@contratalos.com', [email, 'info@contratalos.com'])
```

But I just need to make `info@contratalos.com` to be like a bcc address, I mean invisible to the `email` user.

Comment: I don't see a `info@contratalos.com` anywhere in your post? Are you sure you posted the right code snippet?

Comment: Ya fixed, thank you, what I need is to send it to info@contratalos.com but this should not be visible to the user, ie: project.user.email , or question.user.email

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Nevermind, the message had a delay, now I received it, lol, Thanks!

Comment: This is not an answer ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You should consider [send_mass_email](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/email/#send-mass-mail)

```
subject = ...
message = ...
send_mass_mail((
    subject, 
    message, 
    'no_responder@contratalos.com',
    [email, 'kristian.koci@gmail.com']
), fail_silently=False)
```

Comment: Do you know a way to send it, but to make that other address somehow invisible to the 'email' user?

Comment: try mg['To'] = 'undisclosed-recipients:;'