# Hide Recipient List in Email (BCC) Python - smtp

Tags: python, email, smtp, gmail-api

First I tried using a ['BCC'] header with a list of recipients, but that resulted in the BCC field visible with all recipients also visible.

I read on SO that if I leave out the BCC header and put the recipients directly into the sendmail function that it will send without showing to recipients.  Nope.  Still didn't work.  The recipients were all visible, but still shows the tag "BCC"[image of how it shows up in gmail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwwYN.png)

suggestions? I want a the recipient list to be hidden from other recipients.

```
# Send TV Email

msg2 = MIMEMultipart()
msg2['From'] = fromaddr
msg2['To'] = toaddr 
msg2['Subject'] = "Welcome Message from Puls"
msg2['Reply-to'] = "alister@puls.com"
msg2.add_header('reply-to', fromaddr)
body2 = """Hello New Puls Technician!"""

msg2.attach(MIMEText(body2, 'plain'))
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()
server.login('email', "password")
text = msg2.as_string()
server.sendmail(fromaddr, newTvTechsEmailList, text)
server.quit()
```

Comment: the image you posted, is it from your sent items?

Comment: no, it is from my inbox!

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31797134/send-email-to-multiple-recipients-with-bcc-hidden-address-django-1-6

Answer (score 2):

Check this out [mrts/send-email-hide-recipients.py](https://gist.github.com/mrts/039a9764bf4d23cda1bdac564cd0dfc4#comments):

```
from django.core.mail import send_mass_mail

subject = 'test subject'
message = 'test message'
from_email = 'from@from.com'
recipient_list = ['a@a.com', 'b@b.com', 'c@c.com']

messages = [(subject, message, from_email, [recipient]) for recipient in recipient_list]

send_mass_mail(messages)
```